# awk with numeric comparison incorrect result

Tags: awk

Please advise on the incorrect result, I am trying to understand why this case not working with AWK numeric comparison.

```
echo "100..,900" |awk -F, '{ if ( $1 < 0 || $1 >= 9999.9999 ) { print "Invalid Range" } '
```

No result for above. Expected is Invalid Range

```
echo "100..,999" |awk -F, '{ ( if  ( match ( $1, /[^[:digit:]\.] !=0 )  { print "Not Numeric" }'
```

No result for above. Expected is Not Numeric ( Only should match digit.digit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first script the numeric value of `$1` would be `100` so neither condition would be true as `100` is neither less than `0` nor greater than or equal to `9999.9999` BUT in fact your `$1` is `100..` which isn't a number so it'd be a string rather than numeric comparison being made which still would fail for both conditions.

Your second script has a syntax error.

Comment: Hi Ed, $1 is 100.. , Yes, the script should fail stating some incorrect numeric value in this case, syntx error like cant compare a string or something

Comment: The first script won't fail, it'll behave correctly by just not producing any output. The second script will fail with a syntax error but it'll be nothing to do with "cant compare a string" or anything similar. Try executing it to see what it does.

Comment: @VeeraV awk does some tricky stuff when it boils down to comparison expressions. It is not because you want to use numbers, that awk will use numbers. If one of the sides of the comparison is a string, it will always perform a string comparison by converting numbers to strings. This is what happens in the first case. It sees that `$1` is the string `"100.."`, so it converts the numbers `0` to the string `"0"` and the number `9999.9999` into the string `"10000"` (it used the format `CONVFMT="%.6g"` for this).

Comment: @VeeraV As the ascii character `"1"` is lexicographically _greater_ than `"0"`, the first comparison fails. The second comparison fails on the fourth character as the `"."` character is lexicographically _smaller_ than "0"